# Can a question be offered for bounty twice by a same user?

Tags: support

If a user offers some bounty for his own question and awards it, can he offer bounty for the same question again?

Comment: Note that the [mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) is the first place to check for these things.

Comment: @Qmechanic So, should this question be migrated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, questions (and answers) can be awarded multiple bounties, both by multiple users and by the same user. Examples can be found using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer queries

- [Answers awarded multiple bounties](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/406949/answers-awarded-multiple-bounties)
- [Questions with multiple bounties by any users](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/506465/questions-with-multiple-bounties-by-any-users)
- [Questions with multiple bounties by the same user](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/506472/questions-with-multiple-bounties-by-the-same-user)

Comment: Thank you very much.! Can I offer bounty and award it to a user, and then offer another bounty for same question, but award second bounty to **another** user?

Comment: Yes. See the new queries for examples.